# Spring tests - use real bean to create test bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-bean

I use Spring, and created a test which loads the context using SpringRunner.

I have a bean which looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Properties kafkaStreamsProperties(){
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("A", "B");
    props.put("C", "D");

    return props;
}
```

I would like to extend it in my testing to also contain a property "E" --> "F".

I can easily do it in an inner @TestConfiguration class as follows:

```
public class test{
    public static class MyConfig{
        @Bean
        public Properties kafkaStreamsProperties(){
            final Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("A", "B");
            props.put("C", "D");
            props.put("E", "F");
            return props;
        }
    }
}
```

But then when I change the production code, I'll have to "remember" changing the test too. Is there any way I can get the actual bean from the context and "replace" it with mine (using the actual one)?

Comment: I think you can use @EnableConfigurationProperties so you can reach same properties from test as well as main app.

Comment: If you wanna just change properties you also can override required properties in test by using for example: `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"A=B", "C=D", "E=F"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Test you have [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) to mock a bean or `@SpyBean` to Spy a bean:

> Spring Boot includes a @MockBean annotation that can be used to define a Mockito mock for a bean inside your ApplicationContext. You can use the annotation to add new beans or replace a single existing bean definition.
>
> Additionally, you can use @SpyBean to wrap any existing bean with a Mockito spy